# Copy Entire Row To Another Sheet Except Column C

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google Sheets and I have this code below to copy the last row (via Form On Submit trigger) onto another sheet (not tab).  I'm not sure how to copy over the last row and skip the data in Column C.  It's currently copying the entire row to another sheet successfully, fyi.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
function CopyToAnotherSheet() {

// Delaying this script so that there is enough time to get the Google Doc URL before it starts to fill out the template file
Utilities.sleep(10000); // 10 second delay

// Get Source Spreadsheet
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Get Source Sheet from Spreadsheet
var source_sheet = source.getActiveSheet();

// Get Last Row
var lastRow = source_sheet.getLastRow();

// Get Last Column
var lastColumn = source_sheet.getLastColumn();

// Get Last Row of Data  
var lastRowOfData = source_sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues();

// Creates a one dimensional array  
var oneD_array = lastRowOfData.join().split(",");

// Get the Value of the Manufacturer Cell
var cellValue = source_sheet.getRange(lastRow,3).getValues();


// Copy Last Row to First Sheet
if ( cellValue == "First" ) {
    var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxyyyzzz");
    var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("First");
    target_sheet.appendRow(oneD_array);
}
// Copy Last Row to Second Sheet
if ( cellValue == "Second" ) {
    var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("aabbcc");
    var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("Second");
    target_sheet.appendRow(oneD_array);
}

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just the data from the event object.  It's a lot better than trying to get the last row.

Comment: I'm copying the last row since it's coming in from a Google Form.  I don't know of a way to make a Google Form dump to a specific sheet based on the Manufacturer column.  Can you fill me in on the event object you mentioned?

Comment: So is the event object which contains the same information in two separate structures.  One is called namedValues which is an object and values which is an array.

Comment: The onformsubmit trigger populates the e that most programmers use with triggered events.  On the first line after the function definition with the e parameter add this Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));  it will show you the entire event object.

Comment: You can skip or rearrange columns using the map method of arrays.  Check your favorite Javascript reference for the details.

Comment: I just dragged the row out to the end so I don't have to skip it.  Simple solution, thanks to your last comment there :)

Answer (score 1):

One option you can do is to remove column C value in your 1-d array. Instead of skipping it.

### Sample code:

```
  var lastRowOfData = source_sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues().flat();
  Logger.log("Before removal: "+lastRowOfData)
  // Remove index 2 (Column C value) in the array
  lastRowOfData.splice(2,1)
  Logger.log("After removal: "+lastRowOfData)
```

### What it does?

- Using [array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), change 2-d array to 1-d array
- Using [array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), remove an element in the array

### Output:

```
Execution log
5:10:50 AM  Notice  Execution started
5:10:51 AM  Info    Before removal: a,b,c,d,e
5:10:51 AM  Info    After removal: a,b,d,e
5:10:52 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

### Note:

I removed the `oneD_array` variable in the sample code. If you really want a separate variable for your 1-d array you can use this one:

```
var oneD_array = lastRowOfData.flat();
oneD_array.splice(2,1);
```

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues regarding the solution so I could update it accordingly